# Lambdas vs functions+function pointers for UI events

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have a game engine which includes a built-in in-game editor. the editor is it's own class that is used only as a single object that gets instantiated when the in-game editor is invoked. I also have a (fairly) complete UI system separate from the editor (will be used in the game as well). The editor has UI elements such as buttons that call functions on the editor class, but the UI system will also be used for other non-editor things. So in order for the buttons to access the editor functions and other things not in the editor class, I have to use function pointers, not class method pointers. that function then calls the appropriate editor->Method().

So this is what I have been doing:

```
void MyButton_Click( void ) { if ( editor ) editor->AppropriateMethod(); };
Button some_button( "Button Label", &MyButton_Click );
```

I just learned about lambdas in C++11 and realized I can get rid of all those global functions if I use lambdas instead when instantiating my buttons, like:

```
Button some_button( "Button Label", []() { if ( editor ) editor->AppropriateMethod(); } );
```

However, since I've never used lambdas before today, I want to know if this is even a good idea. I think that so long as I don't need more than one button to call the same editor function, I won't be duplicating code anywhere (the lambda). If I needed to, I'd just declare a global EditorFunction_Click() function like I have been doing.

So other than that, whats the better design here? Lambdas or global functions that are friends to the editor class? Is there any glaring negative attribute about one or the other that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Apologies, I had to edit my question significantly a few seconds after posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and allow the user to decide whether to use a lambda, function pointer, function object, etc? It adds a bit of overhead but it allows for a lot of flexibility.

For example,

```
typedef std::function<void (void)> handler_func;

class Button {
    // stuff...

    Button(std::string label, handler_func func);

    // stuff...
};
```

Then you can create a button that uses any callable object in C++, for maximal flexibility. If it looks like a function, you can use it.

Comment: For a UI system, I'm not concerned about performance since these things only happen upon click. I am concerned however about bloating the size of my executable. I don't know if std:function would do that, I have never used it but it does sound quite nifty.

Comment: Then you're fine to use std::function. It uses a virtual function call under the hood to do some type-erasure magic, but it won't affect you.